# Find 3 elements in each of 3 arrays that sum to a given value

Tags: algorithm, sum

Let A , B, C be 3 arrays of n elements each. Find an algorithm for determining whether there exist an `a` in A, `b` in B, `c` in C such that `a+b+c = k`.

I have tried the following algorithm, but it takes `O(n²)`:

1. Sort all 3 arrays. - `O(n log n)`
2. Temporary array `h = k - (a+b)` - `O(n)`
3. For every `h`, find `c'` in B such that `c' = h - B[i]` - `O(n)`
4. Search `c'` in C using binary search - `O(log n)`

Total is = `O(n log n) + O(n) + O(n² log n)`

Can we solve it in `O(n log n)`?

Answer (score 5):

Your question asks about solving the problem `3SUMx1`, in linearithmic time, which is shown to reduce to `3SUMx3` in randomized linear time. See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/37905/6533) for the reduction.

Unless you're about to publish something very big, I doubt that there can be such a fast algorithm for your problem, which is at least as hard as 3SUM (you can also show the reduction in the opposite direction with some work, too).

**Edit**: To make the above paragraph clear, the linear-time reduction from [3SUM](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/8/contents.html) proves that OP's problem is $\Omega(n^{1.5})$.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand, Can you explain with example. I didn't understand A=B=C=s

Comment: @Suri It's shorthand for an array definition. Suppose you developed some procedure `S` that worked in `O(n lg n)` time, and that procedure, when "called" as `S(A,B,C,k)`, finds the indices `a,b,c` for three arrays `A,B,C` such that `A[a] + B[b] + C[c] = k`. In other words, I'm solving 3SUM by simply calling `S(s,s,s,0)`. No one knows if an linearithmic algorithm for 3SUM exists, so my reduction shows that finding a solution to your question is (at least) as hard as finding one for 3SUM. As I mention, it's possible to show they're actually equal problems, but that is more complicated.

Comment: This isn't quite right; the 3SUM problem requires choosing three distinct elements from the set, whereas the version with three copies of the same array might choose the same element twice. For example, (-1, -1, 2) is a solution for the OP's problem but not for the 3SUM problem.

Comment: @kaya3, they are equivalent with linear-time randomized reduction https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/37905/6533

Comment: @VF1 Yes, but that reduction doesn't involve choosing `A = B = C = s`.

Comment: Ah! Excellent point. I should've read what I said a few years ago before replying to you :). I'll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a variation of the 3SUM problem. you cannot solve it in O(n log n)
it can be solved in O(n^2). The algorithm you described is wrong - it is not considering combinations of various indexes from A and B... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM